# change touchableopacity backgroundColor on button press react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchableopacity

i want to change dynamically generated TouchableOpacity BackgroundColor OnPress in react native.

Comment: Use `TouchableHighlight` instead, with `underlayColor` prop

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem on your own? Can we see your code?

Comment: <TouchableHighlight 
                            style={Appearance[0]}
                            onPress={this.btnClick.bind(this, infoDetails[index])} disabled={isDisabled}>
                            <Text style={Appearance[1]} >{No}</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight >

Comment: btnClick(){//want to change background Color}

Comment: underlayColor is used for hover i want to set backgroundcolor of touchableOpacity

Comment: React Native latest version 0.63.0 has introduced the latest cool component Pressable. You can use that for change the BackgroundColor OnPress Check it out! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLgmJCWyFmk

Answer (score 9):

TouchableOpacity modifies the opacity (as its name says it).
If you want to change the backgroundcolor on a touch, use TouchableHighlight instead

Comment: i have used TouchableHighlight but onPress event how to change TouchableHighlight backrgound Color ??

Comment: i am trying to toggle background color of touchablehighlight onpress...like for example on pressing its background color should turn blue, and on pressing the button again it's background should turn white.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will set a random background colour on press.

How it works is to set the state colour on press and in its style, there is a backgroundColor object which uses the state colour for its value

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const colours = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'indigo', 'violet'];

const getColour = () => colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];

const Button = props => {
  const [colour, setColour] = useState(getColour());
  const handleClick = () => { setColour(getColour()); }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: colour }]} onPress={handleClick}></TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  }
});

export default Button;
```